# JSON converts the number into decimal hex value

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the JSON converts the number to different format and am not able to convert back to actual number that i required

```
new JSONObject("{ \"trxId\": 1611041100656111100142000000000497}\");
Log.e(jsonObj.getString("trxId")
```

Output:

```
1.6110411006561111EE
```

I get this trxId along with more details and this ID will be used for further API calls with server.

Comment: What did you do exactly? How did you get this output?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use **BigDecimal** class here and may be use `doubleValue()` method for that. Use something similar to the following:

```
String requiredNumber = new BigDecimal(stringRepresentationOfYourNumber).doubleValue() + "";
```

That way you can get the full number instead of the scientific notation.

See [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/java_math_bigdecimal.htm)

Comment: I used double requiredNumber = new BigDecimal(jsonObj.getString("trxId")).doubleValue(); but still this gives me the same value

Comment: @SampathKumar Have you confirmed you have printed the exact value? Also see the edit. Let me know if the String is correctly output.